# Print the row and column wise sorted 2 D matrix in a sorted order

Tags: matrix

Given an `n x n` matrix, where every `row` and `column` is sorted in non-decreasing order. Print all elements of matrix in sorted order.

Example:

Input:

```
mat[][]  =  { {10, 20, 30, 40},
                 {15, 25, 35, 45},
                 {27, 29, 37, 48},
                 {32, 33, 39, 50},
               };
```

Output:
(Elements of matrix in sorted order)

```
10 15 20 25 27 29 30 32 33 35 37 39 40 45 48 50
```

I am unable to figure out how to do this.But according to me we can put the 2 D matrix in one matrix and apply the sort function.But i am in a need of space optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Heap would be a good idea here.

Please refer to the following for a very similar question:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallest-element-in-a-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-2d-array-set-1/

Thought the problem in the link above is different, the same approach could be used for the problem you specify. Instead of looping k times as the link explains, you need to visit all elements in the matrix i.e you should loop till the heap is empty.